# ¿Puedo contar los registros en un pipe? [Angular]

Tags: angular6, pipe

Creé filtros con un pipe y lo que quiero ahora es que cuando me filtre mis datos pueda contar cuantos fueron y mostrarlo.

Estos son mis input donde busco dependiendo que quiero:

```
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-group-sm mb-3" placeholder="Nombre del proyecto "
            name="nombre" [(ngModel)]="nombre">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del responsable" name="responsable"
            [(ngModel)]="responsable">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Area" name="area"
            [(ngModel)]="area">
    </div>
```

La tabla con la que muestro los datos:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col ">ID</th>
            <th scope="col ">Proyecto</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let proyectos of todos_proyectos| filter:nombre:responsable:area'>
            <td>{{proyectos.id}}</td>
            <td>{{proyectos.nombre}}</a></td>

        </tr>
```

Y el pipe con el que hago el filtro:

```
  transform(proyectos: any, nombre: string, responsable: string, area: string) {
    if (proyectos && proyectos.length) {

      return proyectos.filter(proyecto => {

        if (nombre && proyecto.nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(nombre.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
          return false;
        }
        if (area && proyecto.area.toLowerCase().indexOf(area.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
          return false;
        }
        if (responsable && proyecto.responsable.toLowerCase().indexOf(responsable.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
          return false;
        }


        return true;
      })
    }
    else {
      return proyectos;
    }

  }
```

Me funciona todo correctamente solo quiero que arriba de la tabla me muestre la cantidad de cuantos fueron los que se filtraron.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Prueba poniendo `{{(todos_proyectos| filter:nombre:responsable:area).length}}` en el html, en el lugar donde quieres mostrar la cantidad. ;)

Comment: muchísimas gracias!!!! si quedo!!!